# Can you execute contained JavaScript in browsers?

Tags: javascript, dom, iframe, ember.js, containers

I want to be able to run JavaScript on my webpage and guarantee that it can be stopped cleanly without causing problems.  You could think of it as running JavaScript as if it was contained in an iFrame but allow it to modify and interact with the root DOM.  That way if I remove the iFrame, the JS dies.

### Use Case/Justification

I want to turn any webpage into a weird mutant SPA. That means taking the traditional HTML, CSS, and JavaScript and then handling page switching myself. To propperly switch pages avoiding artifacts from previously executing JS I'd need to make sure one page's JS doesn't interact with the next page's JS. Ideally, to switch a page it would follow this general formula:

1. Load HTML and CSS with a framework like Ember.js
2. Load all linked JavaScript in a contained environment but with the ability to modify the root DOM
3. When the user clicks a link, **stop all running JavaScript** and return to step 1.

### My Thoughts

I've run tests actually loading a webpage in a full-screen iframe ([like this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7902960/creating-a-full-screen-iframe)) which achieves the level of containment that I want when executing the JavaScript, but it has serious performance penalties. I want the contained JavaScript, with a minimal performance penalty.

One thought I had was after downloading JavaScript, replacing the actual code dynamically. I would change the code to instead of referencing the Window, referencing the [Window.parent](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/parent).

I'm not attached to the idea of using iFrames, but it just seems like it is the closest thing to a "container" that you can get in JavaScript/the browser. I'd love alternatives.

### Related?

github.com/codeschool/javascript-sandbox

instantclick.io/

**shadow DOM**?

### Mini-Followup:

Would it be feasible to build an app like this which would allow for proper handling of both JS life cycles and page switches?

Comment: No way. JS that interacts with a DOM dies only when the DOM dies. So it depends a lot on what exactly the JS does on each of your pages, and how much / which parts of the DOM need to be swapped out.

Comment: Does that mean that for my use case, removing the JavaScript would likely not be needed?  Is it the case that if JS references specific nodes that I then swap out, that JS would die?  Otherwise JS would be intact?  Does this work in my favor? Or would I still have to worry about weird JS interactions when switching pages?

Comment: You shouldn't have to worry about "weird JS interactions" as long as your JavaScript is properly self-contained / modularized, with proper teardown logic. For example, you mention EmberJS in your post, which handles most of the teardown logic automagically, so all you need to take care of is for example removing event listeners you have manually added.

Comment: @KarlFloersch: I meant that if your JS is only referenced (e.g. through event listeners) from the DOM nodes that are removed, then it would die. But if your JS does create some kind of global objects (that are not trivially overwritten), or it does use `setInterval` or so (in a never-ending animation maybe?) then the JS would retain the detached DOM nodes and create a memory leak. So: it depends.

Comment: @PeteTNT Would you say that the vast majority of websites (ex. A wordpress site)  would then not need to run JS perfectly contained if you use Ember.js because most of that teardown logic is done already? I think I might this out and see how it goes. Also is there an easy way to remove the event listeners?

Comment: @KarlFloersch all sites should try and run all their JavaScript contained (by avoiding global variables and states, for example). When considering something like EmberJS (or other MVC/MVVM frameworks) this is a necessity and a design goal, because they are used to make single page apps, where it's very important that all the components or views only affect themselves unless wanted otherwise. For you second question, with those kinds of frameworks, many things such as `click` handlers are handled with the framework itself, so you very rarely actually have to remove the listeners yourself.

Comment: (continued). Due to greatly reduced amount of manual event handlers (and other things you would often setup yourself), you shouldn't have much trouble keeping up a list in your mind what you have done yourself and what steps you should do to tear them down. These kinds of frameworks also often inform you if you left something behind that leaks memory for example.

Comment: @PeteTNT Wow thank you Pete, I'm going to go out and try this--it looks extremely promising. I will report on results!

Answer (score 1):

You can't unload a script once it has been loaded. But you can encapsulate some script in an object, and create or destroy this object.

For instance:

```
var Robot = function(){
    return{
        sayHello : function(){
            alert("Hello!");
        },
        doSomethingElse : function(){
            alert("I'm doing something else");
        }
    }
}

robot = new Robot();

robot.sayHello(); // Actually alerts "Hello!"

robot = null; // the robot is destroyed.
```

In your case, if you load a script via ajax, say this piece of script in an object :

```
{
    sayHello : function(){
        alert("Hello!");
    },
    doSomethingElse : function(){
        alert("I'm doing something else");
    }
}
```

you can then encapsulate this script in a function :

```
var Robot = null,
    robot = null;

$.get('scriptURL', function(ajaxedScriptObject){
    Robot = function(){ return ajaxedScriptObject; };
    createRobot();
})

function createRobot(){
    robot = new Robot();
    sayHello();
    destroyRobot();
}

function sayHello(){
    robot.sayHello(); // Should alert "Hello!" :)
}

function destroyRobot(){
    robot = null;
}
```

Comment: Would this work: I download a bunch of scripts with a few Ajax calls. Then I build a wrapper object and fill that object with the JS I just downloaded. I instantiate this new object which in turn runs all included scripts. Once the user navigates away from this page I then delete the object.

Comment: I think it can work. It sounds a bit difficult, but doable. I can't tell for sure, I've never done such a thing before. If your ajax call returns an object with your script, you can define `Robot = function(){ return ajaxScriptObject; }`

Comment: I have edited my answer with an attempt to adapt my code to your question.

Comment: Please [don't use `delete` for this](http://perfectionkills.com/understanding-delete/). Indeed you would need global variables that were [implicitly created through assignment](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2008/03/horror-of-implicit-globals.html), but that is a **horrible** thing to do.

Comment: Well as an alternative, just set `robot = null`. I would also like to know why my answer has been downvoted. I have edited it.